# Sub string from a string

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I have a String Activation.**August**_2016 I want to get only **August** as a Substring using regular expression in java Plz help
The code I write is:

```
String s = Activation.August_2016
String[] tokens = s.split("[._]");
String before = tokens[0];
System.out.println(before);
```

Output:
Activation

Comment: did you try to check out which mysterious values hide behind index `1` and `2`?

Comment: `String before=tokens[1];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and  [subString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
s.substring(s.indexOf(".")+1, s.indexOf("_"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `string.indexOf(str)` and `string.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)`;

Answer (score 0):

Following code will print august

```
String s="Activation.August_2016";
Pattern p =Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]+.(.*?)_");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find()){
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```